# "Could not connect to wicd's D-Bus interface. Check the wicd log for error messages."

Tags: wicd

I am currently making use of a Wired Broadband. By default NetworkManager shows that the Auto Ethernet is connected. I was unable to browse through any websites in the browser. I had to disconnect & connect the Auto Ethernet several times in NetworkManager or restart Ubuntu to get it fixed. But following these steps is quiet annoying as this issue happens very frequently.

I browsed through the Internet and got to know that WICD Network Manager fixes this issue. Earlier I have been using Ubuntu 12.04 where the same issue was fixed by making use of WCID Network Manager.

Recently I upgraded to 13.10 and as I got the same network issue in default NetworkManager, I have installed WICD NetworkManager but when I try to open WCID, I get an alert message saying,

```
Could not connect to wicd's D-Bus interface. Check the wicd log for error messages.
```

When I click on OK, I get the same message again and when I click on OK again I get the following message,

```
Error connecting to wicd service via D-Bus. Please ensure the wicd service is running.
```

Any help to fix this issue is greatly appreciated as this issue was annoying me since I installed 13.10

Answer (score 10):

This might be a symptom of this bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wicd/+bug/1132529

The solution that worked for me was to run the following commands from the command line (see comment #22 from above link):

```
sudo service wicd stop
rm /etc/resolv.conf
rm /var/lib/wicd/resolv.conf.orig
ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /var/lib/wicd/resolv.conf.orig
sudo service wicd start
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I followed the above set of line commands from Chris and wicd worked. My connections are fine, but I no longer have access to the Internet. I am new to linux and desperately need my internet access back. How do I undo these steps? Any help would be greatly suggested.

Comment: This is performing ugly surgery on Ubuntu's mechanism for managing resolv.conf. Normally /etc/resolv.conf is a symbolic link to `../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` which is written by resolvconf based on information provided to it.