# Cannot access internet due to tampering with resolv.conf

Tags: resolvconf

I'm running Ubuntu 13.10 and attempted to fix an issue with running `wicd` through the instructions from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/370171/62483).

After following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/370171/62483), the program `wicd` works, and my wired and wireless connections are fine, but I cannot use the Internet anymore. My browsers give me errors as if I am not connected.

Are there suggestions to "undo" the command line steps I made?

Answer (score 2):

To undo the damage, do

```
sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf
sudo dpkg-reconfigure resolvconf
```

Answer (score -1):

try this as the ONLY thing in the file

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

in the future `cp resolv.conf resolve.conf.bak`
Now you have a backup file to restore.